# Re-packaging installer with WiX Visual Studio Project

Tags: installation, wix

I've noticed that if I change the files that get installed by my WiX installer, but not the wxs file that the installer is built from, that when I tell my installer to build, it doesn't. In other words, unless I've made a change to my installer itself (currently I do this by just adding a space to the file), it doesn't create a new package.

Is there a way to tell my WiX project to build a new msi file every time? Something less hackish than modifying the wvs file in an insignificant way, or creating a pre-build action that deletes the old msi file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a "Rebuild" instead of just a "Build", of the WiX project.

Comment: I thought about that, but it wasn't an option in the Build dropdown. I bound a keybaord shortcut to it, though, and that seems to have worked. Thanks!